# How to make Handbrake save default audio settings?

Tags: audio, default-settings, handbrake

I click on the "configure default..." button in the audio tab, I set it to the codec/bitrate that I prefer.

However, if I close and re-open Handbrake, these defaults are gone. If I open another file to encode, these defaults are gone. If I'm setting them on a per-use basis, that's sort of the opposite of "default".

I have tried every combination of possible actions within this dialog and Handbrake in general. What am I not getting?

Answer (score 9):

Audio defaults do not save separately from regular presets. If you want a new audio default, it must be included in a new, custom preset.

1. Click the "Configure Defaults..." button, and adjust the settings as you prefer them.
2. Configure the rest of the non-audio settings as you prefer them.
3. Click the toggle presets icon in the top right of the window.
4. Click the "Save preset" button, which is a small plus (+) icon on the bottom left of the right-side popoutpanel. It will ask you to give the preset a name.

This seems to make it stick, assuming that preset has been chosen, even when queuing up multiple files.

I have confirmed this behavior for the latest version, which on OSX is 0.10.2. I'm uncertain if it holds true for older versions (which may be the source of my initial confusion).

Comment: @JohnO Your approach works for saving the audio and subtitles defaults, but I've noticed my custom presets are also saving the video resolution of whichever video was loaded when I created the preset. Is there a way to set up the audo/subtitle defaults without having a video file loaded? I cannot find it.